# Resubscribe event after interrupted

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to call the updatePosition function on mouseMove event from document while mouseMove is not emitted from testEl.current element:

```
const cursor$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'cursor')
const scroll$ = fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(throttleTime(50))
const mousemove$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'mousemove')

const stickymove$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(testEl.current, 'mousemove')
const stickyenter$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(testEl.current, 'mouseenter')
const stickyleave$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(testEl.current, 'mouseleave')


mousemove$.pipe(subscribeOn(animationFrameScheduler), takeUntil(stickyenter$)).subscribe(event => updatePosition(event))
mousemove$.pipe(subscribeOn(animationFrameScheduler), skipUntil(stickyleave$)).subscribe(event => updatePosition(event))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `repeatWhen` to resubscribe when `stickyleave$` emits.

```ts
mousemove$.pipe(
  subscribeOn(animationFrameScheduler), 
  takeUntil(stickyenter$),
  repeatWhen(() => stickyleave$)
).subscribe(event => updatePosition(event))
```